# Operations on files and their locks - code too bulky?

Tags: java, optimization, locking

A couple of hours ago I asked a question on Stackoverflow to find out if there is [a good way to delete files in a folder only if all files are indeed deletable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328328/delete-files-only-if-all-are-deletable-spare-the-innocent) and I got some good answers that led me (I think) in the right direction

Based on the two currently most upvoted answers I scrambled together the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File directory = new File("T:\\download\\test\\1234");

        if (safeDelete(directory)) {
            System.out.println("All deleted");
        } else {
            System.out.println("All kept");
        }
    }

    private static boolean safeDelete(File directory) {
        if (directory == null || !directory.isDirectory()
                || !directory.canWrite()) {
            return false;
        }

        // First get a lock on the directory itself
        FileLock dirLock;
        if ((dirLock = getLock(directory)) == null) {
            return false;
        }

        List<File> filesToDelete = new ArrayList<>();
        List<FileLock> fileLocks = new ArrayList<>();

        // Get a lock on all the files in the folder
        for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {

            FileLock lock;
            if (file.canWrite() && ((lock = getLock(file)) != null)) {
                filesToDelete.add(file);
                fileLocks.add(lock);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Currently unable to write to "
                        + file.getName());
                releaseLocks(fileLocks);
                return false;
            }
        }

        // If we reach this line all the files are locked for us now
        for (File file : filesToDelete) {
            if (!file.delete()) {
                System.out.println("IMPOSSIBLE");
            }
        }
        releaseLocks(fileLocks);

        directory.delete();
        releaseLock(dirLock);
        return true;
    }

    private static FileLock getLock(File file) {
        try {
            return new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel().tryLock();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void releaseLocks(List<FileLock> locks) {
        for (FileLock lock : locks) {
            releaseLock(lock);
        }
    }

    private static void releaseLock(FileLock lock) {
        if (lock != null) {
            try {
                lock.release();
                System.out.println("Released lock on " + lock.toString());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Cant release lock on " + lock.toString());
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But it seems so... bulky to me. There are many return statements in there (I personally like it better when there is only one at the very end), a lot of if-else branching, two `ArrayList`s that manage almost the same stuff and a lot of calls to the `releaseLocks()` method.

The core problem is in my opinion that I have to manage two sets of data on which I both have to operate:

- The Files on which I have to execute the deletion
- And the Locks which I have to release after I'm done

So the question is:
**Can this be done more efficiently?** Should I refactor the `safeDelete()` into more sub-methods?

Comment: Try to rename the whole directory, if that works, create a directory with the old name and delete the moved one. Of course assumes that the OS does not do something fishy with filelocks upon moving...

Comment: you might want to put this as an answer on SO, right now I'm intrigued by the method above and I'd really appreciate a review on this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a class to hold both the file and the lock, so you don`t need to manage two Lists like:

```
public class SafeDirectory {

    private File directory = null;
    private FileLock lock = null;
    private List<SafeFile> deleteableSafeFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public SafeDirectory(String directoryPath) {
        directory = new File(directoryPath);
    }

    public boolean CanBeDeleted() {
        boolean canBeDeleted = false;
        if (directory != null && directory.canWrite() && directory.isDirectory()
                && ((lock = getLock(directory)) != null)) {

            canBeDeleted = true;
            for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
                SafeFile safeFile = new SafeFile(file);

                if (safeFile.CanBeDeleted()) {
                    deleteableSafeFiles.add(safeFile);
                } else {
                    canBeDeleted = false;
                    System.out.println("Currently unable to write to "
                        + file.getName());
                    RelaseLock();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        return canBeDeleted;
    }

    public boolean Delete() {
        for (SafeFile safeFile : deleteableSafeFiles) {
            safeFile.Delete();
        }
        directory.delete();

        RelaseLock();
        return true;
    }

    private void RelaseLock() {
        for (SafeFile safeFile : deleteableSafeFiles) {
            releaseLock(safeFile.lock);
        }
        releaseLock(lock);
    }

    private boolean releaseLock(FileLock lock) {
        if (lock != null) {
            try {
                lock.release();
                System.out.println("Released lock on " + lock.toString());
                return true;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Cant release lock on " + lock.toString());
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    private static FileLock getLock(File file) {
        try {
            return new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel().tryLock();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private class SafeFile {

        private FileLock lock = null;
        private File file = null;

        SafeFile(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }

        boolean CanBeDeleted() {
            return (file.canWrite() && ((lock = SafeDirectory.getLock(file)) != null));
        }

        boolean Delete() {
            return file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```